# Filter Exception Stack Trace from Web API Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api I communicate with.

When exception occurs, I get the following JSON template:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Index was outside the bounds of the array.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.IndexOutOfRangeException",
  "StackTrace": "   at WebApiTest.TestController.Post(Uri uri) in c:\\Temp\\WebApiTest\\WebApiTest\\TestController.cs:line 18\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClassf.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

What I want the JSON to include is just the "Message" and "ExceptionMessage" properties, but still have control on returning the full stack trace on demand.

I've tried using the

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy
```

But seems it's all or nothing, either just the single "Message" property or getting the full object when setting it to "Always".

Any easy way to achieve this?

Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code I use the Exception Filters to do what you are asking for, check the following two links for more details

[Web API Exception Handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

[Web API global error handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

What we do in our code is as follows:

1. Create Exception filter:

   ```
   public class ViewRExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
   {
   // Global context message for the modifying the context response in case of exception
   private string globalHttpContextMessage;

   /// <summary>
   ///     Overriding the OnException method as part of the Filter, which would detect the type of Action and would
   ///     accordingly modify the Http
   ///     context response
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="context"></param>
   public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
   {
       // Dictionary with Type and Action for various Type actions, current method is called by various types
       Dictionary<Type, Action> dictionaryExceptionTypeAction = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();

       // Add an action for a given exception type
       dictionaryExceptionTypeAction.Add(typeof (ViewRClientException), ViewRClientExceptionAction(context.Exception));            
       dictionaryExceptionTypeAction.Add(typeof (Exception), SystemExceptionAction(context.Exception));

       // Execute an Action for a given exception type
       if (context.Exception is ViewRClientException)
           dictionaryExceptionTypeAction[typeof (ViewRClientException)]();
      else
           dictionaryExceptionTypeAction[typeof (Exception)]();

       // Reset the Context Response using global string which is set in the Exception specific action
       context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
       {
           Content = new StringContent(globalHttpContextMessage)
       };
   }

   /// <summary>
   ///     Action method for the ViewRClientException, creates the Exception Message, which is Json serialized
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>
   private Action ViewRClientExceptionAction(Exception viewRException)
   {
       return (() =>
       {
           LogException(viewRException);

           ViewRClientException currentException = viewRException as ViewRClientException;

           ExceptionMessageUI exceptionMessageUI = new ExceptionMessageUI();

           exceptionMessageUI.ErrorType = currentException.ErrorTypeDetail;

           exceptionMessageUI.ErrorDetailList = new List<ErrorDetail>();

           foreach (ClientError clientError in currentException.ClientErrorEntity)
           {
               ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();

               errorDetail.ErrorCode = clientError.ErrorCode;

               errorDetail.ErrorMessage = clientError.ErrorMessage;

               exceptionMessageUI.ErrorDetailList.Add(errorDetail);
           }

           globalHttpContextMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exceptionMessageUI, Formatting.Indented);
       });
   }
   ```

Here ViewRClientException is my custom exception class with following schema:

```
public class ViewRClientException : Exception
{
    public ViewRClientException(ErrorType errorType, List<ClientError> errorEntity)
    {
        ErrorTypeDetail = errorType;
        ClientErrorEntity = errorEntity;
    }

    public ErrorType ErrorTypeDetail { get; private set; }
    public List<ClientError> ClientErrorEntity { get; private set; }
}
```

Action method defined above ensures that we get the relevant Json serialized string, which can be used as Json response, similar is the job of SystemExceptionAction for any generic exception, which is not custom. In fact I have many other custom exception categories. Current filter modifies the HttpContext.Response

2. Register the Exception filter in WebAPIConfig.cs, as shown below:

   ```
     public static class WebApiConfig
       {
         public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
         {
           // Web API configuration and services

           // Adding the Generic Exception Filter for the application
           config.Filters.Add(new ViewRExceptionFilterAttribute());

           // Web API routes
           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ControllerActionApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{userID}",
               new {userID = RouteParameter.Optional}
               );

           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ControllerApi", "api/{controller}/{userID}",
               new {userID = RouteParameter.Optional}
               );
         }
      }
   ```

Now it should work providing custom message as you need

Comment: For me it works flawlessly. Your essential requirement of having data in the format you need is possible using custom exception

Answer (score -3):

Incomplete Example. ClientError & ErrorType ErrorTypeDetail

If you are going to contribute please include everything!

Comment: please use the "Comments" link for comments and save the "Answer" link for actual answers